# How to convert xml Element and its child nodes into String in Java?

Tags: java, xml, string, dom

Hi I want to convert XML node and its child into a string with its node names.

For example I get a node from XML document which is look like this:

```
<Name>
  <Work>*86</Work>
  <Home>*86</Home>
  <Mobile>*80</Mobile> 
  <Work>0</Work>
</Name>
```

I want to convert whole node into string. With nodenames, not only text. Any help in this regards is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how can you xml document look like *86 *86 *86 0 ? i am missing something

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you post the code

Comment: Node node = doc.getElementBytagName("Name").item(0); i want the whole node in string is that achievable.or not.

Comment: see http://projectwownow.blogspot.com/2008/08/java-node-to-string-conversion.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can use JDom [XMLOutputter](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html) subject to the condition that your Element is an org.jdom.Element:

```
XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();
String s = outp.outputString(your_jdom_element);
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use a transformer for that:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
transformer.transform(source, result);

String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Comment: im working on android 2.0 in which Transformer clases are not available,there is any another way?