# Getting weird characters when converting from XML Element and its child nodes to String in Java

Tags: java, xml

I used the transformer code mentioned in below link to convert xml element and its child to xml string

[How to convert xml Element and its child nodes into String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390385/how-to-convert-xml-element-and-its-child-nodes-into-string-in-java)

The problem is i am seeing some weird characters , only first element text content is in plain text rest is some weird encoding

For quick reference here is the code

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter()); 
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString(); System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Input looks like below

```
<Info ID="_65ae9406-63c9-4fd5-93a0-5ab1b5a3f3c7"
            IssueInstant="2012-02-11T09:53:52.722Z" Version="2.0"
            xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            <Issuer>https://localhost:8080/</Issuer>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_65ae9406-63c9-4fd5-93a0-5ab1b5a3f3c7">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform
                                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>IDHt1dgdR9k/toaocOxCVMiJhPjqRPyNSou4ywBA2YM=
                        </ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>o5lTezATnGX+sllItfElMuabaFlpBed8wc8lAieigQ4JiIsgjIdHbg7gyyCpgk</ds:SignatureValue>

            <ds:Signature></Info>
```

Comment: What does the input look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an XML declaration which specifies the encoding of your XML file (UTF-8 in the example). Maybe it helps :)

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: The XML i posted is actually the content of org.w3c.dom.Element , so there is no way i can add declaration

Answer (score 0):

Look at: [DOMImplementationLS serialize to String in UTF-8 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636792/domimplementationls-serialize-to-string-in-utf-8-in-java)

Notice this piece:

```
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
```

and:

```
String xml = output.toString();
```

The example above is calling `toString` on the string writer, you're calling it on the `streamResult`.

Trying breaking it out like that example does and see if that works for you.

Comment: No same issue , doesn't help. Thanks for your time